# Получила проект на yii в котором надо добавить окно с угадыванием города. Это моя первая работа. Как проект развернуть и начать работу?

Tags: yii2, composer

Друзья! Как развернуть проект сделанный другим программистом в приложении yii1?

Answer (score 2):

Судя по вопросу ,вопросов два, на второй "и Вообще, как приступить к написанию кода?" ответ один или знать yii2 или начать разбираться  в нем.Этот Вопрос в принципе не корректен. Равнозначен вопросу,я хочу собрать атомную бомбу дома, с чего мне начать?. По первому вопросу тоже очень много неизвестных, нужно настроить голый yii2 с сайта, посмотреть работает ли сервер с ним, а дальше разбираться что в конкретном проекте используется, версия php. mysql.Иногда для запуска проекта стороннего, приходится пересобирать весь сервер, даже менять Apache на nginx. Так что в общем проблема с которой вы столкнулись понятна, но в ней очень много неизвестных.Так что ответ может быть лишь такой, максимально приблизитесь к конфигурации сервера на котором работает проект.Может какие то ошибки уйдут и сами.

Comment: Ну, я так и думала. Была уверена в ответе в этом стиле. Ничего нового.

Comment: А как вы хотели? есть наверное целые курсы по yii2, в которых минимум часов 30 теории и бесконечная практика, а вы задаете вопрос с чего мне начать? ни  кто вашего кода  даже не видит, и как кто то, должен методам гадания вам ответить? Вот у меня есть один проект, с чего мне в нем завтра начать писать? Есть вопросы конкретные например сколько будет 2+2, а есть вопросы имеющие кучи вариантов решений и нюансов которые нужно учитывать. Ваш вопрос относится ко второму типу, и чтоб на него кому либо ответить, нужно взять все данные вашего проекта, и начать делать это за вас.